# Python|Pandas|Data Science-Outliers -Imputing with median values the outliers

Tags: python, pandas, median, outliers

I have a dataset which consists of outliers in the salary columns. I have detected the outliers and the corresponding indexes however i am trying to impute median values for these indexes based on the groupby of values in that particular column.
Eg:

df
empid salary rank city country
1      2000   1    Bangalore India
2      30000  1    California USA
3      400000 1    California USA
4      500000 1    Bangalore  India
5      3600   2    Bangalore  India

Here we can see that the for specific rank :1 and city:bangalore , Country :India we have a outlier  of salary 500000 .Same as for USA,California and rank 1 : Outlier is 400000

Used the below code to get indexes of these outliers :

Code:

```
Q1 = df['salary'].quantile(0.05)
Q3 = df['salary'].quantile(0.95)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
whisker_width = 1.5
lower_whisker = Q1 - (whisker_width*IQR)
upper_whisker = Q3 + (whisker_width*IQR)
index=df['salary'][(df['salary']>upper_whisker)|(df['Fixed_Amount_INR']<lower_whisker)].index
```

Now wanted to impute the median for these specific outliers  of these indexes based on the group by of the columns i.e.

df['salary']= df.groupby['rank','City','Country']['salary].iloc[index].transform('median')

It issnt working s expected.
Appreciate help.
expected output:

```
df
empid salary             rank   city           country      
1      2000               1      Bangalore      India  
2      30000              1      California      USA 
3      new_median_value   1      California      USA     
4      new_median_value   1      Bangalore       India
5      3600               2      Bangalore       India
```